# Which object does var belong to in NodeJs module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

this is my code

```js
var a=1;
console.log(global.a);
console.log(this.a);
```

both print `undefined`. And it indicates that `a` doesn't belong to either `global` or `this` (current module).

I want to know which object `a` var belongs to.

Comment: See https://repl.it/@MaheerAli/Test its showing logging `1` both times. Can you edit it to show the problem.

Comment: @MaheerAli this clearly mentions Node.js, which does exactly as the question describes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f@/LLFIIdHW0JorOT@vOD8nVS8nP10jPSc/KTFHL1ETVbgkI7MYJPj/PwA "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: Tony, `a` belongs to the top level module scope, which is not an object accessible by the language.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - Maheer's link is running in a node environment.  And I verified that it is working the same in his repl as it does when I run it in my node terminal on my local machine.

Comment: @AlexanderNied REPL is not the same as code running in a module. REPL evaluates at global scope, module code evaluates in a function scope isolated to the module. Based on the description of the behavior given, the above code is running in a file evaluated by Node.js as a module.

Comment: @AlexanderNied if you want to reproduce the behavior in `repl.it` which appears to be running `index.js` directly in a Node.js REPL rather than as a module, use [this example](https://repl.it/repls/SlategreyAffectionateParticle).

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - OK, I understand now, and verified you are correct.  Thanks for clarifying for me.  @TonyBenjamin-- is there something specific you are trying to accomplish?  If you want to reference the variable in the module, you would simply do so by the variable's name, and if you want to assign it to the global namespace, you could define it as a property on `global`, rather than as a variable.  Or is this question merely out of curiosity?

Comment: @AlexanderNied I wanna imitate the "call" function after I read a blog. And this is the question I met in the process.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks. I think I need more knowledge about scope.

Answer (score 4):

To understand this you need to know about the *Module Wrapper* in Node.js.

All the JavaScript code run by Node.js is not run directly, instead wrapped by a function call which is called by Node internally.

The Module Wrapper:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {  
    // You code goes here  
});
```

The code which actually runs is:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {  
    var a=1;
    console.log(global.a);
    console.log(this.a);
});
```

So the `var a` is inside the scope of an anonymous function not part of the `global` object also not part of `this`(Since this function is not called with any object i.e Function​.prototype​.call(null) )

Refer [The module wrapper](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper)